# Win32 WinHttp: Correct way to query custom response header?

Tags: winapi, http-headers, winhttp

I want to query **ETag** header from response headers *(Of course ETag is HTTP standar, but it is not defined as a flag in WinHttpQueryHeaders function)*. this is Microsoft's [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815295(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
HRESULT ReadHeader(
    __in HINTERNET requestHandle, 
    __in_z WCHAR* headerName, 
    __in ULONG queryFlags)
{
    HRESULT hr = NOERROR;
    WCHAR headerBuffer[256];
    ULONG headerLength = sizeof(headerBuffer);

    if (!WinHttpQueryHeaders(
        requestHandle,
        queryFlags,
        NULL,
        headerBuffer,
        &headerLength,
        WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX))
    {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        goto Exit;
    }

    wprintf(L"%s: %s\n", headerName, headerBuffer);

Exit:
    return hr;
}
```

It can use to query value with flags. But how I can do with ETag? I tried:

```
WinHttpQueryHeaders(
    requestHandle,
    NULL,
    L"ETag",
    headerBuffer,
    &headerLength,
    WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX)
```

with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `WinHttpQueryHeaders` a `dwInfoLevel` set to `WINHTTP_QUERY_CUSTOM` which:

> Causes `WinHttpQueryHeaders` to search for the header name specified in
>   the `pwszName` parameter and store the header information in `lpBuffer`.